# What is the difference between the electrical components on a micro-chip and ones on an eyes-observable circuit?

Tags: components

For example, an IC or "microchip" where everything must be micro-engineered on to it uses the same electrical components such as resistors, transistors, etc.

But I looked around online and noticed that transistors are actually eyes-observable(i.e., you can see and touch them, and there are some on my comp's motherboard).

But so they must be micro-implemented? Are they the same components, only micro?

I don't understand this, and it would be nice if someone could make sense of it.

Answer (score 4):

Discrete transistors are packaged in various ways. Some of the earlier designs were packaged in metal cans about the same size as the small black-plastic packages you probably see on a motherboard.

Here's a phot I took just now, the ruler is marked in mm (the "1" is 1 cm).

[image: Two Transistors]
<sup>*Photo by RedGrittyBrick*</sup>

Here's an enlarged photo of one opened up,

[image]
<sup>*Image by [Rolf Süssbrich Rsuessrb](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Small_Transistor_Metal_1.jpg)*</sup>

You can see that the actual transistor is much much smaller than the metal container.

As other people have pointed out, you can make the transistors much smaller still - so long as they don't need to carry much electrical current.

Here's a picture of a transistor of the sort of size you'd find in a CPU

[image]
<sup>*Image from [TomsHardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/infineon-multi-gate-transistor,3902.html)*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, what you can see is an opaque black epoxy *package* protecting the component.

Transistors have a unique property in that the production process can be scaled down in much the same way as reducing or enlarging a photograph. Consider this picture of a MOSFET from wikipedia: [image]

The pads will probably be about a milimeter across, but the design in the middle can be any scale. Smaller transistors can handle less power but are fundamentally the same as the large ones.

Comment: Common pad sizes are usually smaller than 0.1mm (for reference)

Answer (score 0):

`But so they must be micro-implemented? Are they the same components, only micro?`

Because smaller is better. Unless you want a computer the physical size of your house. They don't **have to** be small. And since transistors used for computing are for data and signals, low voltage and current capacities, they don't require the same large housings and paths as high amperage transistors do. So they are designed to scale.

For comparison, the same applies to hard drives:
[image]